# Django: Initial Value from view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

How is possible to get initial value from the view? What parameter should I use in form?

views.py

```
def cadastro_usuario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = cadastroForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = cadastroForm()
    return render_to_response("registration/registration.html", {
        'form': form, 'tipo_cadastro': 'PF',})
```

forms.py

```
class cadastroForm(UserCreationForm):

    tipo_cadastro = forms.CharField(XXXXX)
```

Comment: Get what initial value from the view?

Comment: Actually I need hard code some variable in the view and them save in the UserProfile (as I explained to J. Landgrave)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, based on your comment in response to @J. Lnadgrave, let's assume you have a "user_type" property on your UserProfile model that can be set to your "normal" user or "company" user...

```
#your_app.constants
NORMAL_USER = 0
COMPANY_USER = 1

USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (NORMAL_USER, "Normal"),
    (COMPANY_USER, "Company"),
)


#your_app.models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from your_app.constants import USER_TYPE_CHOICES

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOne(User)
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)


#your_app.forms
from your_app.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile

    user_type = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)


#your_app.views
form django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from your_app.constants import NORMAL_USER, COMPANY_USER
from your_app.forms import UserProfileForm
from your_app.models import UserProfile

def normal_user_registration(request):
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None,
        initial={'user_type' : NORMAL_USER})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_profile_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return render(request, 'registration/registration.html',
        {'user_profile_form' : user_profile_form})

def company_user_registration(request):
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None,
        initial={'user_type' : COMPANY_USER})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_profile_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return render(request, 'registration/registration.html',
        {'user_profile_form' : user_profile_form})
```

This is a pretty long-winded way to approach this, but I thought it made it pretty evident how to pass that initial value to your form. Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel that you should initialize any data in a view, since it's better suited to manipulate requested data, such as operating on an ordinary request or setting up a query. I think you're looking for this [tidbit on initializing values for a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values), since that's my assumption after reviewing your example code that you've given us. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually, I need use the same form and model for two different view. Just one value will change in each view. Sorry, let me explain better, I have two types of users on my site: "normal user" and "company user" both will use the same form and model to register, but in the frontend will have 2 different links to registration. In the model, I have a field that will be filled as the type of user... So... I thought to do 2 views just changing one variable.  Did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you need exactly, but it seems to me that checking out [Dynamic initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)
may be useful. You can define an initial value for a form in the view like this:

```
f = cadastroForm(initial={'tipo_cadastro': 'Initial Value!'})
```